# Stream API collect() use personal class Word intsead of Map

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

How can i transform my map to class Word which contain word and his frequency

```
List<Word>
```

or i have to  create similar to that

```
Map<String, List<Word>> wordFreq
```

**I avoid some methods for brevity**

```
public class Word implements Comparable<Word> {

    private String content;

    private int frequency;
}
```

```
class CONTAINER {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 StringBuilder userWords = new StringBuilder();
userWords.append("some sequence of words");

Map<String, Long> wordFreq = Stream.of(userWords.toString().split(" ")).parallel()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toString, Collectors.counting()));

            List<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Long> a : wordFreq.entrySet()) {
                words.add(new Word(a.getKey(), Math.toIntExact(a.getValue())));
            }
    words.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.getContent() + " : " + s.getFrequency()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a convenience method forEach in Map:

```
List<Word> words = new ArrayList<>();
Stream.of(userWords.toString().split(" "))
    .parallel()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toString, Collectors.counting()))
    .forEach((k, v) -> words.add(new Word(k, Math.toIntExact(v))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream.map(..)` method. In your case that would be:

```
List<Word> words = wordFreq.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .map(entry -> new Word(a.getKey(), Math.toIntExact(a.getValue())))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```